# Lua Split String by Root Note and Chord Name

Tags: string, split, lua

I need to split lot of chord names into key and chord type:

```
name = C
name = C#
name = Db
name = C#maj7b5
name = Cmaj7b5
name = Dbmaj7b5
```

so the root will always be a letter by it's self or with # or b, a letter by it's self or with just # or b ,the root will need to = maj by default.

```
root = C
chord = maj
root = C#
chord = maj
root = Db
chord = maj
root = C#
chord = maj7b5
root = C
chord = maj7b5
root = Db
chord = maj7b5
```

I can get the root name:

```
name1 = string.match(name, "%a#") 
name2 = string.match(name, "%ab") 
name3 = string.match(name, "%a")
```

if I get nil value in name1 and name2 then root = name3. Just need the chord name also.

EDIT: used:

```
chord, pos = nil, 0
chord, p = string.match(region_name, "=%s+([^\n]+)()", pos)
if not p then end
pos = p
root, chord = string.match(region_name, "(%w[#b]?)(.*)$")
if not chord or #chord == 0 then chord = "maj" end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env luajit

local text = [[
   name = C
   name = C#
   name = Db
   name = C#maj7b5
   name = Cmaj7b5
   name = Dbmaj7b5
]]

local chord, pos = nil, 0
while true do
   local chord, p = text:match("=%s+([^\n]+)()", pos) 
   if not p then break end
   pos = p
   local root, chord = chord:match("(%w[#b]?)(.*)$")
   if not chord or #chord == 0 then chord = "maj" end
   print(("root = %s"):format(root))
   print(("chord = %s"):format(chord))
end
```

Explanation:

The difficulty of the problem is about finding the right regular expressions.

On the first regular expression:

```
text:match("=%s+([^\n]+)()", pos)
```

you just fetch anything that is after the equals sign. The regular expression also remembers the last position of the match, so on the next iteration you can start from the last position. If there's no match the last position will be nil. In that case the program exists.

Now you get the chord, you split it in two elements:

```
chord:match("(%w[#b]?)(.*)$")
```

The first parts gets one letter (%w) and then the characters '#' or 'b', which are marked as optional (?). The other part of the expression gets whatever characters (.*) until the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks, there is no list of chord names, it is just from another function **chord_name**, so it won't have a list: 'local text = [[
   name = C
   name = C#
   name = Db
   name = C#maj7b5
   name = Cmaj7b5
   name = Dbmaj7b5
]]' the string is **chord_name**

Comment: OK, so in that case I believe you are mostly interested in the body of the loop. Just grab the pieces that are more interesting for you and plug them into your script. OTOH, if the answer worked for you could you mark it as accepted? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Why `%w`?  It should be `%u` or `[A-G]`: `"([A-G][#b]?)(%S*)"`

Comment: Right, %w is a broader match (alphanumeric) while [A-G] matches only chord letters.

Comment: Thanks it should do the job, I'm just having trouble working out how to use it with `local retval_region, _, region_pos, region_end, region_name, region_index, region_color = reaper.EnumProjectMarkers3(0, region_id)` as it gets it from a function call not a table, it gets the chord name from "region_name", it is an API in Reaper DAW.
The last reply got cut short as I have to remember not to hit the enter key for a new line as it post the reply then unless you edit it in 5mins you kicked out.

Comment: Technically (the best kind), they're Lua patterns, not regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, used: `chord, pos = nil, 0
chord, p = string.match(region_name, "=%s+([^\n]+)()", pos)
if not p then end
pos = p
root, chord = string.match(region_name, "(%w[#b]?)(.*)$")
if not chord or #chord == 0 then chord = "maj" end`